# NullPointerException occuring after null check java

Tags: java, null, nullpointerexception

I have this if statement

```
if((check1==null||!check1.isSolid())&&(check2==null)||!check2.isSolid())
```

it throws a null pointer exception because check1 or check2 are null, but i don't understand why it is doing this, because i am checking for the null condition before i am accessing the object and if the object is null why would java bother checking isSolid because it would have already been true.

Comment: try this : if(  (check1==null||!check1.isSolid() ) &&( (check2==null)||!check2.isSolid() ) )

Comment: @Satya - It looks like you just added some whitespace.  That isn't going to make any difference.

Comment: Stephen I corrected the parenthesis as well

Comment: For the future, you can do yourself a favor and not try to jam all that together with no newlines and spacing =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your messed up your parenthesis. Java will group your statement together like this:

```
((check1 == null || !check1.isSolid()) && check2 == null) || !check2.isSolid()
```

If `check1` is `null` and `check2`, is `null`, the first statement will evaluate to `true`. The problem occurs when your move on to the second statement, since `check2` is `null`, `check2.isSolid()` will through a `NullPointerException`.

Change your parenthesis to

```
(check1 == null || !check1.isSolid()) && (check2 == null || !check2.isSolid())
```

Answer (score 1):

You mixed up the parentheses. Try:

```
if((check1==null||!check1.isSolid())&&(check2==null||!check2.isSolid()))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
boolean check1_result = (check1 == null) ? true : !check1.isSolid();
boolean check2_result = (check2 == null) ? true : !check2.isSolid();

if (check1_result && check2_result)
// do work...
```